# Реализация алгоритма RLE для строки

Tags: java, алгоритм, rle

Тренирую работу с классом `String`. Стоит задача по RLE:

> На вход подается строка (допустим, `Jjjjaavvva`). Результатом должно быть `Jj4a2v3a`.
>   Макс. количество повторов - 9. Для `aaaaaaaaaa` (10 букв `a`) это должно записываться как `a9a1`.

Я думаю пробежаться по массиву этой строки и где есть совпадения сделать `substring` этой области и `split`, а потом считать кол-во и делать конкатенацию.

Как это реализовать лучше? Может, есть готовые решения?

Comment: Что-то у вас примеры друг другу противоречат. В первом если символ встречается один раз, то он просто пишется в результат. Во втором он пишется с числом повторений 1.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Строковые типы, замена символов: заменить одинаковые подряд идущие символы на “сигнатуру”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739967/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно пройти один раз по всем символам строки и собрать новую строку в `StringBuilder`.

При просмотре очередного символа идёт проверка:

- если достигнут конец строки, или текущий символ встретился уже 9 раз подряд, или очередной символ не равен текущему, то записываем текущий символ и количество его повторений (количество - если оно больше 1) в результат, в качестве текущего символа устанавливаем очередной, а количество повторений - в 1.
- иначе увеличиваем количество повторений на 1.

Код реализации:

```
public static String getRLE(String str)
{
    if (str == null || str.equals(""))
    {
        return str;
    }
    char currentChar = str.charAt(0);
    int currentCharCount = 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = i < str.length() ? str.charAt(i) : 0;
        if (i == str.length() || currentCharCount == 9 || c != currentChar)
        {
            sb.append(currentChar);
            if (currentCharCount > 1)
            {
                sb.append((char)(currentCharCount + '0'));
            }
            currentCharCount = 1;
            currentChar = c;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCharCount++;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Для строки `aaaaaaaaaabbbccca` результатом будет `a9a1b3c3a`.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш код. Цифры добавляются от 2 до 9, если один раз стоит то цифра мне не нужна. Если символ попадается один раз, то замену мы не делаем просто его переписываем. И еще регистр при замене нужно как-то учитывать допустим Hhh это будет Hh3, а у меня сейчас H1h2.

Comment: @striker92 не записывать количество повторений некорректно. Если у вас исходная строка была `12`, и вы её так и оставите, то при декодировании она внезапно станет `11`, так как `2` будет расценено как количество повторений `1`. Вам оно надо? Каким образом `Hhh` может преобразовываться в `Hh3`? Варианты `h3` и `H1h2` мне понятны, а `Hh3` - нет. Думаю, вам стоило более четко и корректно сформулировать условия в вопросе.

Comment: Регістр символів при заміні враховується. Наприклад, рядок:

Hhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeellooooo
      

Буде перетворено на:

Hh9h4e4l2o5
      

Зверніть увагу: якщо кількість повторів більше 9 то потрібно розбити закодовану інформацію на дві групи. Наприклад:

hhhhhhhhhhhh     
буде замінено на:
h9h3
     
Дані для кодування будуть надходити як аргументи командного рядка (лише один рядок). 
Зверніть увагу на перевірку вхідних даних: на вході НЕ може бути null але може бути пустий рядок. 
У випадку пустого рядку на вході Ваше застосування повинно вивести на екран пустий рядок.

Comment: @striker92 предлагаете в Google-переводчик этот текст вбивать? Всё же официальный язык этого ресурса - русский. И, заметьте, в первом примере `Hhhhhhhhhhhhhh` - то есть 1 `H` и 13 `h`. которые в результате превращаются в `Hh9h4` - никаких фокусов с регистром букв и никаких преобразований `Hhh` в `Hh3` - только в `Hh2`.

Comment: @striker92 для одного повторения я код изменил, раз уж это учебное задание, не связанное с реальным миром. Насчет преобразования `Hhh` в `Hh3`, по-моему, неправы вы: должно получаться `Hh2` (с учетом опускания `1` у `H`).

Comment: Вы правы, это я не доглядел задание. Нужно учитывать регистр, следовательно после большой не идет цифра, преобразование не нужно. Разобрался уже. Пойду разбирать классы StringBuffer, StringBuilder. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А как реализовать процесс обратный кодированию? Бежим по строке если видем цифру то добавляем предыдущий символ столько то раз?

Comment: @striker92 да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Я решила так:

```
public class Application {
    String str = "";

    public void rleString(String s) {
        int count = 1;
        if (s == "") {
            System.out.println("");
            if(s == null){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        } else {
            char[] masChar = s.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i <masChar.length-1; i++) {
                if (masChar[i] == masChar[i + 1]&&count<9)  {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    if(count==1){
                        str=str+masChar[i];
                    }
                    else {
                        str = str + masChar[i] + count;
                        count=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count==1)
            {str=str+masChar[masChar.length-1];}
            else
                {str=str+masChar[masChar.length-1]+count;}

        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Очень элегантное решение. Сделаю ещё и через StringBuilder()", к чему относится эта фраза?

Comment: К решению, присланному @Regent

Comment: Если вы ссылаетесь на уже данные ответы, то конкретней, как вы сделали в комментарии. Обычно, как и в вашем случае, такая ссылка не нужна в ответе, т.к. не несёт в себе полезной информации.