# Строковые типы, замена символов: заменить одинаковые подряд идущие символы на “сигнатуру”

Tags: c++, строки

Встал перед вопросом, необходимо в введенном тексте заменить одинаковые подряд идущие символы на "сигнатуру". С использованием `#include <vector>` все решается довольно просто, но использовать его нельзя (размер обновляется сам). Как реализовать данное задание с использованием массива типа `char` или строки `string`?

Имеем строку аааа345рр, пользователь вводит число 2, все символы подряд идущие 2 или более раза меняются на сигнатуру {количество, символ}. Имеющаяся строка на выходе {4,а}345{2,о}

Comment: На счет алгоритма думал поступить так: Цикл идущий по строке,
каждый символ после первого сравниваем с текущим для сравнения, если он будет равен - увеличиваем счётчик символов и запоминаем позицию текущего, иначе - если счётчик повторов больше 1, то вырезать из строки все символы от текущего, который сравниваем, до текущего, который в цикле и помещаем на вырезанное место счетчик повторений, но как "динамически" тогда изменить размер массива, если я например 3 символа 'a' заменю на {3,a}?

Comment: @jfs, при замене части строки на сигнатуру, меняется размер массива, проблемы с обновлением размера массива.

Comment: @jfs, `while (str[i+1]!='\0') 
{
    if (str[i] == str[i + 1]) 
             for (int x=0;(x<"размер строки" && str[x]!='\0');x++) ` далее я делаю замену, где соответственно меняется размер строки, размер необходимо обновить, проблема здесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы из `аааа345рр` получить `{4,а}345{2,о}`, то есть чтобы реализовать [Кодирование длин серий (RLE)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9):

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt rle_encode(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
  if (first == last) // empty
    return d_first;

  auto prev = *first++;  // previous char
  uintmax_t count = 1;
  for ( ; first != last; ++first, ++count) {
    if (prev != *first) { // ended run of the same consecutive elements
      d_first = write_rle_run(d_first, prev, count); // write the run
      prev = *first; // start new run
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return write_rle_run(d_first, prev, count);
}
```

Это трансляция из Питона [rle_encode() функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595163/23044).

`write_rle_run()` записывает найденную серию подряд идущих символов в результат:

```
template<class OutputIt, class C>
OutputIt write_rle_run(OutputIt d_first, C character, uintmax_t count) {
  if (count > 1) {
    *d_first++ = '{';
    for (char digit : std::to_string(count))
      *d_first++ = digit;
    *d_first++ = ',';
    *d_first++ = character;
    *d_first++ = '}';
  }
  else {
    assert(count == 1);
    *d_first++ = character;
  }
  return d_first;
}
```

Это работает и для массива:

```
const char a[] = "aaaa345pp";
char output[5*(sizeof a)/2];
rle_encode(std::begin(a), std::end(a), output);
```

и для string:

```
std::string text = "aaaa345pp";
std::string s;
rle_encode(std::begin(text), std::end(text), std::back_inserter(s));
```

и для потоков ввода/вывода:

```
std::istream_iterator<char> chars{std::cin}, eof;
rle_encode(chars, eof, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

[Полный пример кода](https://ideone.com/l6yR4t).

В `write_rle_run()` можно передать желаемое число повторений от пользователя и адаптировать `if (count > 1)` условие.

Чтобы выполнить преобразование в обратную сторону, можно использовать [`rle_decode()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740564/23044).

Comment: а как используя этот алгоритм вернуть текст в исходное состояние, то есть декодировать текст?

Comment: @LokenGarvel' это уже отдельный [простой] вопрос. Вот [пример для похожего формата на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718035/23044). *Не имеет значения какой алгоритм данные генерирует.* Как обратить зависит в первую очередь от формата данных и в каком виде вы их получаете. Можно регулярные выражения использовать или можно руками серии  `{count,char}` искать и распаковывать. [Пример как по одной цифре на Си числа распознаются](https://askubuntu.com/a/879196/3712). Попробуйте реализовать решение и если возникнут конкретные сложности, задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

C использованием `string` все решается небольшой функцией. Вопрос закрыт

```
   while (first != str.end()) 
    {
        string::const_iterator second = first + 1;

        while (second != str.end() && *first == *second)
            ++second;

        size_t n = second - first;

        if (n > 1) {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << n;
            ret +=  string("{")+ss.str() + string(",") + *first + string("}");
            first = second;
        }
        else {
            ret += *first++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/210280)

Comment: @Harry: посмотрите на [предыдущую редакцию с кодом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/740178/2). Я на Мете [обсуждение завёл](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6315/23044)