# Декодирование длин серий RLE, обратное преобразование, после обработки алгоритмом

Tags: c++, строки

Имеется функция, преобразовывающая в строке все повторяющиеся подряд идущие символы в сигнатуру вида {число, символ}, как имея преобразованную строку привести к исходному состоянию. Преобразовать, преобразовал, вернуть в исходное состояние не получается.

```
string get_string(string str, int number)
{
    string ret;
    string::const_iterator first = str.begin();

    while (first != str.end()) {
        string::const_iterator second = first + 1;

        while (second != str.end() && *first == *second)
            ++second;

        size_t n = second - first;


        if (n >= number) {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << n;
            ret += string("{") + ss.str() + string(",") + *first + string("}");
            first = second;
        }
        else {
            ret += *first++;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Итераторами никогда особо не пользовался, если не сложно, покажите обратное преобразование с минимальным комментарием. Хоть итератор и своеобразный указатель, не совсем понимаю все тонкости его работы.

Исходная строка : "аааа3444    rrr", строка после обработки: {4,а}3{3,4}{3, }{3,r}

Comment: Приведите пример исходной строки и строки после обработки этим алгоритмом.

Comment: @Юрий Коротков, добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string str_in = "{4,а}3{3,4}{3, }{3,r}";
std::string result;

for (auto it = str_in.begin(); it != str_in.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == '{') {
        ++it; // Переходим к числу повторяющихся символов

        // Определяем количество повторяемых символов.
        // Так как число может состоять из нескольких символов, то делаем это в цикле
        std::string str_number;
        for (; '0' <= *it && *it <= '9'; ++it) {
            str_number += *it;
        }
        unsigned symbol_number = std::stoi(str_number);

        ++it; // Переходим к символу который повторяется

        // Заполняем повторяющиеся символы
        for (int symbol_count = 0; symbol_count < symbol_number; ++symbol_count) {
            result += *it;
        }

        ++it; // Пропускаем символ '}'
    }
    else {
        // Заполняем еденичный символ
        result += *it;
    }
}

std::cout << result << std::endl; // "аааа3444   rrr"
```

Comment: если вы считаете, что `int` достаточно (так как вы используете `stoi()`), то и используйте `int` для symbol_number вместо `unsigned` (тем более, что ниже цикл у вас int использует,  чтобы signed<unsigned не сравнивать и ясно было что переполнения не будет в цикле)

Comment: @jfs В целом, это все не имеет какого то значение, так как алгоритм еще требует доработки стабильности. К примеру, нет проверки выхода за приделы строки. Я использовал 'unsigned' на автомате, так как число повторяемых символов не может быть отрицательным.

Comment: верно. Для сравнения, я добавил [версию, которая пытается ошибки отлавливать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740564/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы декодировать `{4,a}b4c{2,p}` в `aaaab4cpp`, проверяя ввод на ошибки:

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
std::tuple<InputIt, OutputIt, bool>
rle_decode(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
  bool success = true;
  while(first != last) {
    if (*first != '{') {
      *d_first++ = *first++; // copy the input to the output as is
    }
    else { // decode {count,char} RLE run
      ++first; // skip {

      // read count
      uintmax_t count = 0;
      for ( ; first != last && '0' <= *first && *first <= '9'; ++first )
        count += 10 * count + (*first - '0'); //NOTE: ignore overflow

      if (count == 0 || first == last || *first++ != ',' || first == last) {
        success = false;
        break;  // error
      }

      // output current character *count* times
      d_first = std::fill_n(d_first, count, *first++);

      if (first == last || *first++ != '}') {
        success = false;
        break; // error
      }
    }
  }
  return std::make_tuple(first, d_first, success);
}
```

Пример из строки в строку:

```
std::string text = "{4,a}b4c{2,p}";
std::string s;
rle_decode(std::begin(text), std::end(text), std::back_inserter(s));
std::cout << s;
```

Можно сразу печатать:

```
rle_decode(std::begin(text), std::end(text), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Также как и [в `rle_encode()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740246/23044), можно потоки ввода вывода передавать:

```
std::istream_iterator<char> chars{std::cin}, eof;
rle_decode(chars, eof, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

[Полный пример](https://ideone.com/d1gknK).